# ORDER BY based on multiple WHERE cases, is this possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

Events can be a 1 day event or be an on-going event. This means that sometimes events can go for multiple days, weeks, or months.

As it is now, it is possible to sort the query result by END in ascending order (those expiring earlier shows first) or START in ASC (events based on start date). However, in both cases I have limitations that I am trying to reduce as much as I can.

When sorting by END, sometimes events that are ongoing and have already started get pushed to later in the list.

When sorting by START, events that have already started and are ongoing end up taking up the first sections of the list.

Is it possible to chain multiple ORDER BY statements based on logic rather than columns?

For example:

Get events that are expiring within the next 7 days:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Get events that are still ongoing between 7 days from today and ending within 14 days:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

Get all remaining events...

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE end >= NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

Basically, is it possible to join these into one query?

```
SELECT * FROM data
ORDER BY (logic 1), (logic 2), (logic 3);
```

Alternatively, I did get it working with running 3 separate queries and building up the result array on the server-side, but would like to simplify my code if possible.

Hoping that an end result will always show a list of events that will be expiring within 7 days first, then events that are happening between 7 - 14 days (could be starting or ongoing), then events that are still ongoing or starting after 14 days from today.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Sure thing, will keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your SQL database, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE (end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) -- logic 1
    or (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) -- logic 2
    or (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) -- logic 3
order by 
  case 
    when (end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) then 1 
    when (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) then 2
    when (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) then 3
    else 4
  end asc
;
```

You may also use `union all`:

```
  SELECT 1 as sort_order, * FROM data 
  WHERE (end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
union all
  SELECT 2 as sort_order, * FROM data 
  WHERE (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY)
union all
  SELECT 3 as sort_order, * FROM data 
  where NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY
```

The sort_order is probably not needed, but if you get your result not in the order of `select`, you may then use a subquery; also your database might forbids you from using `order by` in an `union all`.

```
   select * 
   from (
      SELECT 1 as sort_order, * FROM data 
      WHERE (end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    union all
      SELECT 2 as sort_order, * FROM data 
      WHERE (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    union all
      SELECT 3 as sort_order, * FROM data 
      where NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY
   ) order by sort_order asc -- and any other key
```

I would personally go for the `union all` if possible (it is more readable).

Comment: Thanks! Testing out the multiple options that everyone has given, definitely like how Union All looks, easier to understand. This version worked well for my case as well!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using MySQL.

use the `case when .. then .. end` in the select clause, then order by this column.

```
select *, case 
 when end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY then 1 
 when NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY then 2
 else 3 as priority
from data 
order by priority
```

Also, you can use the `case` in the order by clause.

**Note**: I didn't take care of your business logic, so test it well, just giving you how you can achieve it, hope it helps.

Comment: Nitpick: to get a useful result set, you should add the actual columns from data in your `SELECT` list :-)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt May I ask what the benefits are when selecting the actual columns? Is this more of a security thing or does it have an impact on the querying speed as well?

Comment: @amd This worked great! Testing out the other answers below using union all for learning purposes, but thank you!

Comment: @ElbertBae The original query selected *only* the priority and none of the data. Performance-wise, it doesn't matter whether you explicitly enumerate all columns or use `*` - although I'd recommend always explicitly enumerating the columns in production code (with `*`, you might run into nasty surprises if the ordering of column changes or columns are added / removed).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a UNION where you select the data set and have a column that has the order you want. e.g.

```
SELECT 1 as orderby,* FROM data WHERE end < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, * FROM data WHERE NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= start AND end < NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, * FROM data WHERE end >= NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY
ORDER BY orderby, end
```

P.S.  I would suggest you don't use SQL Keywords such as end for column names in your database, that can sometimes cause issues,  enddate would be a better column name.

P.P.S. Avoid doing SELECT *, it is better to explicitly list the columns that you want.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great, all of the examples that's been posted work well, but I do enjoy the fact that Union All removes duplicates. This might be a silly question, but avoiding SELECT * versus using it, is it more of a security implication or does it impact the querying speed as well?

Comment: @ElbertBae Avoiding SELECT * is just future proofing.  If in the future you decide to add some columns to the table and whatever is using the results can't handle the new columns, then it will break.  Also you probably will want to select just the columns you need, rather than everything for performance.